# Get nth type from the tail of tuple in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am wondering if there is a way to access nth type from the tail of the tuple type, such as...

```js
type UserType = 'vendor' | 'customer' | 'staff';
type SignUpParameters = [string, string, boolean, UserType];

type isAdmin = NthTypeOfTuple<SignUpParameters, -2>; // boolean
```

Comment: Why not define `isAdmin` first and pass that into your `SignUpParameters` instead of `boolean`?

Comment: Fair question! The point of doing this is simply that I don't know which function parameters I will be accessing. `Parameters<fnType>` always returns tuple with varied length. The library would assume that second last or nth last type will be the of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to do this.  There are various requests for features which would enable this, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) which would allow you to compute something like `T['length'] - 2` at the type level and index that way.

For now, you could write your own utility type that works this way, but it will almost certainly have weird edge cases, and require [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) operating on [variadic tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types).

One possible approach is to build an `At<T, I>` utility type to emulate the behavior of [`Array.prototype.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at), as I (half-jokingly) [suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47660#issuecomment-1025054467) in [microsoft/TypeScript#47660](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47660):

```
type Reverse<T extends readonly any[], U extends any[] = []> =
  T extends readonly [infer F, ...infer R] ? Reverse<R, [F, ...U]> : U

type At<T extends readonly any[], I extends number> =
  `${I}` extends `-${infer J}` ? 
    [never, ...Reverse<T>] extends infer R ? 
      J extends keyof R ? R[J] :
    undefined : 
  never : 
T[I];
```

The `Reverse<T>` type is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that reverses a tuple, and then `At<T, I>` uses [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to strip the minus sign off `I` if it's negative, and then index into a shifted reversed version of `T`.  Yes, it's awful:

```
type UserType = 'vendor' | 'customer' | 'staff';
type SignUpParameters = [string, string, boolean, UserType];    
type IsAdmin = At<SignUpParameters, -2>;
// type IsAdmin = boolean
```

But it works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgFXNAvFA5ANwgOwBMB7RLKAH2wGMBXOYYgWyXKqwYEMAzbrAbgBQoSFADKASwDm+GGAAKnRJxbAkcKJgDaDRBPxSANFF36jUAEbFiAGwid8x+ElSQAukOFooAJQh5EBAAeZCgIAA81Ig1EexJ8GxAoBxAtNycwyIJCDRS0zSg0gD5NQSgoUIionKhYznjEwv1uJCgAMWMAOm7m1p83KAB+X391CCCfYy0OqG7OmDcSgC5YQS9RAEFgEMzqmLjiBKS89KgASV3sjXxaJgskEvQyqAADABIAbzOAXxfL6NeAFpPr1EFAAFK-IaFfCjRBdbp+ALBZBFAZVK5QUG+aHg-41ADWEBAxG4OOGPi04IGS2etCIEG4+gghCgK1hATZFS0Zw8axE0DOcA2hCY+gKWyCkhkckUylU6mMgIATEUhAB6dVQAXnYWi8WYKy2ez4IA)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz! I think I found similar answer from google search as well. I will post what I did for completeness. But, it's pretty close to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging into different typescript blogs and post, I found that I can do this only by reversing tuple such as following:

```js
export type TReverseTuple<Tuple extends any[]> = Tuple extends [
   ...infer Rest,
   infer Last,
]
   ? [Last, ...TReverseTuple<Rest>]
   : [];

export type TTuplesNthFromTail<
   Tuple extends any[],
   N extends number,
> = TReverseTuple<Tuple>[N];

type UserType = 'staff' | 'vendor' | 'customer';
function accessLogs(range: [Date, Date], timestamp: Date, userType: UserType) {
   return false;
}
function registerUser(
   firstName: string,
   lastName: string,
   timestamp: string,
   userType: UserType,
) {
   return false;
}
type A = TTuplesNthFromTail<Parameters<typeof accessLogs>, 1>; // Date
type B = TTuplesNthFromTail<Parameters<typeof registerUser>, 1>; // string
```